# Odd Issue with Sessions Originating form NATed Network

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

I am having an odd Apache issue where one device of two devices on the same remote network will timeout at 60 seconds.  I have been able to extend that to two minutes by setting TimeOut to 120 seconds, but the second device is still loosing connection with the server.  A get a generic 'Could not open the page as the server stopped responding' (Safari).

My test is to load a simple page (php script that only prints date) on my desktop and on my iPad Pro.  I wait exactly 60 seconds and refresh the iPad and I get the error.  This result can be replicated on many end-user networks.

My first thought was Apache needed to maintain a session for each entity on the remote network as Apache would see them originating from the same IP, but mod_session did not have any effect.

The target server is an AWS Instance running Centos 7, Apache 2.4 (fully patched) and PHP 5.6.4.  (I know, there is a project underway to update to PHP 7.X).

I will note that this was not happening on a Centos 6 server running Apache 2.2, and the existing environment only has 4 or less users as it is a development environment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Settings:

httpd.conf:

Timeout 300
KeepAlive On

Prefork settings:

```
 StartServers       8<br>
 MinSpareServers    5<br>
 MaxSpareServers   20<br>
 ServerLimit      256<br>
 MaxClients       256<br>
 MaxRequestsPerChild  4000<br>
 MaxConnectionsPerChild 0<br>
```

Some additional notes: This only seems to happen with PHP files, even those files that contain only text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that might stumble across the same symptoms: The issue was a kernel setting brought over from an old version of the OS.

"net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1" was set and it should not have been.  The command

```
"sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=0"
```

resolved everything.  If you are having the same problem, simply run that command and look for immediate results.

If you need to revert, just run:

```
"sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1"
```

to undo.  Of course, adding it to the /etc/sysctl.conf file will make it a permanent change.

Hope this helps someone at some point.

Comment: related on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426253/tcp-tw-reuse-vs-tcp-tw-recycle-which-to-use-or-both